# Mysql password expires when I stop Mysql service

Tags: mysql

I am having this problem, not sure if it's normal behavior but I use the following to set a password in mysql for root.

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('hidden')
```

Now everything works fine until I stop mysql service and start again, then I can get into mysql using the same password `hidden` but the password has expired and I have to set it again.

I tried to set a rule to never expire passwords but it doesn't work either

```
SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;
```

is this normal?

Comment: Try something like `ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;`

Comment: What version of `MySQL` are you running? `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD(...)` is deprecated as of `5.7.6` and will be removed in future releases. `SET PASSWORD = 'clearpasswd'` is not deprecated. Use `ALTER USER user IDENTIFIED BY 'clearpasswd';`.